# NGINX - Balance protocol UDP

Tags: nginx

I need to configure Nginx to balance my UDP requests on port 514, to send logs via syslog. My setup below is working, but the IP I am sending is from the balancer, I need the real IP from the client. I tried with the parameter below, but to no avail.

```
  # Load balance UDP‑based DNS traffic across two servers
  stream {
    upstream syslog_upstreams {
    server X.X.X.X:514;
}

server{
    #set_real_ip_from X.X.X.X:;
     listen 514 udp;
     proxy_pass syslog_upstreams;
     proxy_protocol on;
}


}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: My first guess is: Look in the file proxy_params (and/or include it) and use `http_x_requested_with`. But I am unsure with UDP and if your client can read the X-Requested-With header.

Comment: I added this directive proxy_protocol and started to recognize the client IP, but it only logs the IP only once. Then log in the proxy ip. Do you know the reason?

Comment: If your backend receives the header the first time (and that leads to success in this case), then you must make sure that this header is also sent with all subsequent calls. To monitor your network traffic, I recommend Wireshark. You can also feed this with tcpdump output from Linux. The search is a disaster, but once you have found your UDP packet, you can see a lot with right click, follow, UDP stream (e.g. the headers, if they exist at all at UDP). tcpdump in connection with Wireshark have often saved my ass (time!) and I don't think you have a problem with encrypted data with UDP, easy.